# Який найточніший переклад слова "безвозмездно"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Google пропонує варіант `безоплатно`, що, на мій погляд, не повністю відповідає значенню слова `безвозмездно`.

Інші варіанти, що зустрічались в джерелах - `добробільно`, `безплатно`, `добровольчо`, `безкорисливо`, `безкоштовно`.

Як на мене, значення `безвозмездно` найкраще описується як `без вигоди для себе`. `Безоплатно` теоретично може бути з вигодою для себе, `добровільно` - з домішками примусу, а в `безвозмездно` цих домішок немає. Особисто я схиляюсь до `безкорисливо`, але виникає питання, чому Google пропонує `безоплатно`.

Тому питання, який варіант перекладу слова `безвозмездно` є найточнішим?

Comment: Я хочу точне (найкраще?) значення "безвозмездно". Я особисто сприймаю це як "без вигоди для себе". Але я можу помилятись. Тому і цікавить думка спільноти. Запитання відредагував. Залишається питання, чи потрібно оформити "безкоштовно, безплатно і безоплатно" як окреме запитання?

Comment: @sashaeve, річ у тім, що про точне значення слова «безвозмездно» — це [сюди](//rus.stackexchange.com/) або [сюди](//russian.stackexchange.com/). А от про підбір (українського) слова для вже відомого значення — це вже до нас. Але я зрозумів, що Ви маєте на увазі.

Comment: Поправив кілька одруків. Там в одному місці є слово «добробільно» — я не упевнений, чи це одрук, чи так і задумано. Не став виправляти.

Comment: `Задарма` - синонім до `безоплатно`, `без зиску для себе` - краще що спадає на думку як синонім для `без вигоди для себе`. `беззисково` виглядає як калька і навряд чи літературне

Comment: Якщо Ви розіб'єте на два окремі питання: «еквівалент слова `безвоздмездно`» та «відмінність між `безкоштовно`, `безплатно` і `безоплатно`» — то я зможу відповісти на друге. Тобто я не кажу, що *треба* чи *краще* розбити — просто я відповіді на перше не знаю. Ну, або тут можу написати часткову відповідь, якщо хочете.

Comment: Додав нове запитання: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/%D0%AF%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B6-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: @sashaeve будь ласка, поясніть детально як розуміти вашу думку «Безоплатно теоретично може бути з вигодою для себе»?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Особисто мені подобається варіант **`ЗА СПАСИБІ`**.

Він такий, наче власне український, а не перекладений з російської (принаймні, часто вживаний на Полтавщині).

Також, здається, значення відповідає відчуттям автора запитання (*Я особисто сприймаю це як "без вигоди для себе"* - (с) з коментарів).

Підтвердження знаходимо в СУМ-11.

[СПАСИБІ](http://sum.in.ua/s/spasybi)

> ♦ **За спасибі — *без плати***. *Дід знову забалакав: — ..Я людям
>   служу, громаді служу — так, за хліб, за спасибі... от що!* (Панас
>   Мирний, I, 1949, 158); [Денис:] *Чорта з два я їх [ховрахів] ловитиму
>   за спасибі!..* (Марко Кропивницький, II, 1958, 11); *В пляшці була не
>   горілка, а кислий оцет. Хоч оцту теж за спасибі не купиш, але Сивокіз
>   образився і, відпльовуючись, пішов з весілля* (Петро Панч, На
>   калиновім мості, 1965, 10).

Утім, знаходимо цей вислів і серед варіантів перекладу ***`безвозмездно`*** (переадресоване на ***`бесплатно`***) в [Російсько-українському словнику сталих виразів онлайн](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/index2.php)

> [БЕЗВОЗМЕЗДНО](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/search2.php?fullname=%E1%E5%E7%E2%EE%E7%EC%E5%E7%E4%ED%EE&submit=%C8%F1%EA%E0%F2%FC).
>   Див. БЕСПЛАТНО.
>
> [БЕСПЛАТНО](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/search2.php?fullname=%E1%E5%F1%EF%EB%E0%F2%ED%EE&submit=%C8%F1%EA%E0%F2%FC)
>
> **Бесплатно сделать, получить, дать что-либо**.
>
> Зробити, одержати, дати що безплатно (неплатно, безвідплатно); без
>   плати зробити, одержати, дати що; (розм.) дурно (задурно, дармо,
>   даром, задарма, на дурницю) зробити, одержати, дати що; **за
>   спасибі**; (жарт.) за так гроші (грошей).
>
> || *Усім дівкам продає, своїй Домні дурно дає*. Чубинський. *Чи бачили
>   — робити на дурницю!* Кочерга. ***Як тільки прийдете — стукніть у моє
>   віконце. Просто так, за спасибі***. *Земляк. Для тебе ні по чім: за
>   так гроші*. Кониський.

У доповнення до запропонованого жартівливого варіанту ***`за так гроші (грошей)`*** ще скажу, що на Полтавщині почасти можна почути ***`Відтанцюєш(те)!`***.

Наприклад, діалог: - **Скільки з мене/що я винен (за роботу/послугу)? - Відтанцюєш(те)!**.

Тут ***`відтанцюєш(те)`*** означає: "*Платити нічого не треба, за спасибі, але коли у мене (або в моїх дітей) буде весілля або яке інше свято, то щоб гарно танцював(ли), щоб було весело "на усе село", це й буде найкращою віддякою.*"

**UPD.** [@Bohdan Kuts](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/334/bohdan-kuts) додає, що на Львівщині кажуть ***`За дякую!`***

**UPD 2.** Щоправда, [@Artemix](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/69/artemix) підказує, що оригінальне ***`безвозмездно`*** має певне стилістичне забарвлення (*книжне, офіційне*), на противагу ***`за спасибі`*** (***`за дякую`***).

Comment: _ЗА СПАСИБІ_ - у нас ще просто кажуть **За дякую**.

Comment: @BohdanKuts, а де це у вас? Я можу апдейтити відповідь з посиланням на Вас.

Comment: Північ Львівської області.

Comment: У "за спасибі" ("за дякую") втрачається канцелярсько-штампований присмак слова.

Comment: @Artemix, а хіба у *безвозмездно* саме (і тільки) такий "присмак"? Я не знайшла таких тверджень. Якщо Вам відомі якісь застереження щодо стилістичного забарвлення цього слова, поділіться, будь ласка.

Comment: Сова у мультику Про Вінні-Пуха вживає саме це слово через його складність і книжковість. Вона хизується своєю псевдоосвіченістю і підбирає саме такі слова щоб вразити оточуючих.

Comment: Словник Ушакова: "БЕЗВОЗМЕ́ЗДНЫЙ, безвозмездная, безвозмездное (книжн., офиц.). " http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/744746

Comment: @Artemix, дякую! Мабуть, я не настільки знаюсь на російській. Ніколи навіть не замислювалась над тим, що *безвозмездно* має певне стилістичне забарвлення. Мені воно зажди здавалось досить звичайним словом. "Не бійтесь заглядати у словник", навіть якщо цей словник - російський)

Comment: @Artemix, доповнила відповідь.

Answer (score 4):

З того що таке "[возмездный](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)"

> **Возмездный** – відплатний, віддячний, заплатний, (*за хорошее*) нагородний, (*за преступление*) карний:

Виходить, що "безвозмездный" - це **безвідплатний**.

Тобто російська фраза *Безвозмездно, т.е. даром* перекладається як *Безвідплатно, тобто даром/задурно.*

Comment: У мене «[задурно](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=29155&page=965)» асоціюється в першу чергу з другим значенням, що «задурно» (тобто «марно», а не «безплатно»). А є ще слово «[даром](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=20912&page=708)» — за словником майже ті самі значення («безплатно», «марно», «легко»), але в мене в першу чергу асоціюється саме з потрібним значенням (бо від «дар»).

Comment: Не даром, а задарма

Answer (score -2):

Безвозвратная финансовая помощь — безповоротна фінансова допомога. Тож "безвозвратно" можна перекласти і як "безповоротно".

Comment: Можна, але тільки в контексті "безповоротньої фін. допомоги"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/4083)