# Яка відмінність між словами "безкоштовно", "безплатно", "безоплатно"?

Tags: значення-слів, синоніми

Колись зустрічав інформацію, що є відмінності між значеннями слів `безкоштовно`, `безплатно` і `безоплатно`, зокрема, в юриспруденції.

Чи так це, чи всі ці слова є повними синонімами?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Якщо орієнтуватися на СУМ, то можна зробити висновок, що ці слова - абсолютні синоніми.

> [БЕЗКОШТО́ВНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/bezkoshtovnyj), а, е. **Який не
>   потребує коштів, оплати; безплатний**. *Навчання, одяг і харчі там [в
>   школі] були безкоштовні* (Семен Скляренко, Легендарний начдив, 1957,
>   11)...
>
> [БЕЗПЛА́ТНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/bezplatnyj), а, е. **Який не
>   оплачується, не потребує оплати.** ... *Не так легко було дістати
>   безплатну путівку поза чергою й саме туди, куди радила лікарка* (Юрій
>   Яновський, II, 1954, 102).
>
> [БЕЗОПЛА́ТНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/bezoplatnyj), а, е. **За який не
>   платять; безплатний**. *Опір буржуазії проти безоплатної передачі
>   землі селянам.. неминучий* (Ленін, 26, 1951, 18). :)

Якщо розглядати в **юридичному контексті**, то, на мій погляд, в першу чергу варто звернутися до [Податкового кодексу України](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/2755-17).

У ПКУ термін ***`безплатний(а, е, о)`*** не зустрічається взагалі.

Як поняття (термін) розкривається ***`безоплатний(а, е, о)`***:

> 14.1.13. **безоплатно надані товари, роботи, послуги**:
>
> а) товари, що надаються згідно з договорами дарування, іншими
>   договорами, за якими не передбачається грошова або інша компенсація
>   вартості таких товарів чи їх повернення, або без укладення таких
>   договорів;
>
> б) роботи (послуги), що виконуються (надаються) без висування вимоги
>   щодо компенсації їх вартості;
>
> в) товари, передані юридичній чи фізичній особі на відповідальне
>   зберігання і використані нею;

У тексті кодексу ***`безоплатний(а,о)`*** вживається 78 разів.

**`Безкоштовний(а, е, о)`** в ПКУ зустрічається 6 разів, у значенні, що дублює ***`безоплатний(а, е, о)`***.

> 197.1.12. *безкоштовної* передачі рухомого складу однією залізницею або підприємством залізничного транспорту загального користування
>   іншим залізницям або підприємствам залізничного транспорту загального
>   користування державної форми власності.
>
> *Безкоштовна* передача рухомого складу між підприємствами в межах залізниці проводиться за поданням начальника залізниці на основі
>   рішення Укрзалізниці, а в межах Укрзалізниці - згідно з наказом її
>   генерального директора. *Безкоштовна* передача рухомого складу
>   оформляється актом приймання-передачі відповідно до законодавства.
>
> *Безкоштовна* передача здійснюється в разі:
>
> ...
>
> 197.1.23. *безкоштовної* передачі приладів, обладнання, матеріалів, крім підакцизних, науковим установам та науковим організаціям, вищим
>   навчальним закладам III-IV рівнів акредитації, внесеним до Державного
>   реєстру наукових організацій, яким надається підтримка держави;
>
> ...
>
> 353.6. Особи начальницького і рядового складу податкової міліції мають формений одяг та знаки розрізнення і забезпечуються ними
>   *безкоштовно*.

Слід відмітити, що в деякі нормативні документи були внесені зміни, якими термін ***`безплатний`*** було замінено на ***`безоплатний`***. Припускаю, з метою уніфікації термінології з ПКУ.

У [Цивільному кодексі України](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/435-15) та [Господарському кодексі України](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/436-15) ***`безкоштовний`*** і ***`безплатний`*** (у різних відмінках) не вживаються, а ***`безоплатний`*** (а, е, о) - 30 разів у ЦКУ, 17 разів - у ГКУ.

Хоча, до прикладу, в [Законі України "Про національну поліцію"](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/main/580-19) зустрічаються всі три слова (у різних відмінках): ***`безоплатний`*** - 11 разів, ***`безплатний`*** - 5 разів, ***`безкоштовний`*** - 4 рази.

Comment: Дякую за грунтовний аналіз. Можете прокоментувати ось ці публікації: http://mises.org.ua/main/34-alex-martynov/131-free-or-costless.html та http://probapera.org/publication/13/25257/bezkoshtovno-chy-bezplatno-bezoplatno.html, де вказують на певні відмінності між словами?

Comment: @sashaeve, чесно кажучи, трошки плутані пояснення, як на мене. Чіткої диференціації я не побачила. Втім, аргументи Alex Martynov щодо економічного підгрунтя перегукуються з юридичним, наведеним у відповіді.

Comment: @sashaeve У доповнення скажу, що, на мою думку, СУМ, як радянський словник, відображав тодішні реалії, тому й орієнтація була на *безплатний*, бо треба було створювати ілюзію *безплатних благ* за соціалізму-комунізму. Сучасне українське законодавство, як бачимо, хоча ще й не повністю, тяжіє до терміну *безоплатний*, тобто той, що таки має вартість, ціну, але передається/отримується без оплати. У запитанні був акцент щодо юридичного контексту, який я й спробувала висвітлити.

Answer (score 1):

На сайті [Онлайн Корректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/) бачимо:

> Замініть прикметник безкоштовний, якщо мовиться про щось, надане за 0
> грошових одиниць, на стилістично кращий варіант: безплатний,
> безоплатний.
>
> **Втім, прикметник безкоштовний зі значенням «який не потребує коштів,
> оплати», зафіксовано у численних словниках і живому мовленні.**

Також на [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53393/25817.html) (взято із газети "Хрещатик"):

> Безкоштовний, безкоштовно – безплатний, безплатно
>
> **Потрібно надавати
> перевагу словам безплатний, безплатно, що правильніше утворені**. В
> одному з офіційних документів я прочитав, що громадяни мають право
> безоплатно здобувати освіту. А чому не безплатно? Прислівника
> безплатно утворено за продуктивною моделлю, на зразок без відмови –
> безвідмовно, без користі – безкорисно. Його всі розуміють і всі
> вживають. Цього не скажеш про незграбне слово безоплатно, котрим
> багато мовців не хоче користуватися.

Ще також наткнувся на цікаву думку (однак, саме джерело не можна вважати надійним) на сайті [Австрійської економічної школи](http://mises.org.ua/main/34-alex-martynov/131-free-or-costless.html):

> Обидва слова сприймаються як тотожні по значенню. Але неважко
> помітити, що одна має справу із коштами (отже, затратами), а друге із
> платою (отже, ціною).
>
> Що ж тоді безкоштовне? В вужчому значенні, неекономічні блага, тобто
> такі, для споживання, яких не треба використовувати обмежені засоби
> (неекономічним благом, для прикладу, буде повітря); але в ширшому
> значенні, всі блага, бо навіть для споживання повітря, ми змушені
> використовувати свої обмежені калорії, також свій обмежений час. Але
> якщо безкоштовне повітря в певній мірі легітимне твердження,
> безкоштовна освіта чи медичне забезпечення - це оксюморон.
>
> Безплатне - більш ближче до того, що під цим часто розуміється.
> Безплатне - те, що купляється за ціну 0 грошових одиниць. Тим не
> менше, якщо ми вважаємо, що безплатне - це безкоштовне, то ми глибоко
> помиляємося. Для того, що отримати безплатну медицину-освіту, її треба
> створити чиїмось коштом-затратами. Звичайно, тут можна сказати, що це
> може бути створено немонетарним коштом, тобто не платою, стягнутою з
> когось іншою. Але, як можна побачити у вище наведеному прикладі із
> повітрям, кошти-затрати зовсім необов'язково мають бути монетарними.

Висновок:

Бесплатний краще вживати у значенні "те, що коштує 0 грошових одиниць"

Безкоштовний - "той, який не потребує коштів, оплати"

Безоплатний - згідно до онайн корректора - "те, що коштує 0 грошових одиниць" (хоча, газета "Хрещатик" взагалі рекомендує не вживати це слово).

Answer (score 0):

Я вважаю що не потрібно обмежувати себе вживанням слова безкоштовно, чи тільки безплатно використовувати. Є прекрасні синоніми слова ["безкоштовно"](https://nenws.com/samoosvita/slovnyk-ukr/bezkoshtovno-bezplatno-bezoplatno-darom-slovnik/#%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B8), їх використовувати в сучасній українській мові можна і ніхто вам, це не може заборонити. Посудіть самі, українська мова наскільки різноманітна, та багата синонімами, що слідувати правилами з [онлайн коректора](https://onlinecorrector.com.ua/uk/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE/) чи [словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53393/25817.html) не критично.

Comment: Це погана відповідь, оскільки, по-перше, вона навіть не є відповіддю на поставлене питання. І, по-друге, вона заснована на власному суб'єктивному досвіді, що категорично не схвалюється на SE ресурсах. Нікого не цікавить і нікому не потрібна ваша суб'єктивна думка.

Comment: я мав наувазі усне спілкування, при написанні статей, документації тощо, потрібно дотримуватись норм і правил написання або вживання тих чи інших слів. Можливо Ви праві)

Comment: `я мав наувазі усне спілкування, при написанні статей, документації тощо, потрібно дотримуватись норм і правил написання або вживання тих чи інших слів` - > Нікого не цікавить і нікому не потрібна ваша суб'єктивна думка. Читайте [вікі SE](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help), інакше ваші відповіді/питання будуть мінусуватися/закриватися/видалятися.

Answer (score -1):

"Безоплатний" утворене від словосполуки ["без оплати"](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=phraserow&phrase=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7+%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8). Тому нічого поганого в ньому нема.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit]. Сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/) підкажуть, як можна покращити ваш допис.